# vertical marquee effect in FLEX

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, marquee

I want to show the TEXT with the marquee effect in my application.

Marquee effect is only on the text that is in the BOX and that should be in the Vertical.

Please Help me asap.

Comment: please visit this [Link](http://ntt.cc/2008/04/14/simple-tips-to-realize-the-marquee-effect-in-flex-with-source-code.html)

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine for me.

```
    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.effects.Move;

        import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;

        // Define a new Zoom effect.
        private var zMove:Move = new Move();

        private function toLeft():void {
            // Set duration of zoom effect. 
            zMove.duration = 20000;
            zMove.xFrom = 0.1 ;
            zMove.xTo = -label2.width;
            zMove.target = label2;
        }

        private function rightToLeft():void {
            // Set duration of zoom effect. 
            zMove.duration = 20000;
            zMove.xFrom = Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
            zMove.xTo = 0.1;
            zMove.target = label2;
        }

        private function zoomeffect():void {
            if(zMove.xFrom != 0.1) {
                toLeft();
            } else {
                rightToLeft();
            }
            label2.visible=true;
            zMove.play([label2],false);
        }

    ]]>
     </fx:Script>

          <s:Group width="100%" bottom="0" height="50" contentBackgroundColor="#d0382b" >
         <s:Label id="label2" text="Marquee effect in flex "
              top="25" height="50" fontSize="15" fontStyle="italic" 
              fontFamily="Verdana" verticalCenter="0" visible="false"
              creationComplete="moveffect()" effectEnd="moveffect()"/>
      </s:Group>
```

Comment: I want to create horizontal scrolling text Like Marquee Without blank spacing in between text repetetion.

My problem came when I wanted to loop it. I used Move function in Adobe Flex. However, it would only loop when the text was done scrolling off of the page. I want it to continuously scroll and repeat the text, without there being a space. How it is possible in Adobe Flex?? Please reply as soon as possible